# reference_wrapper Referencing Primitive

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, functor, reference-wrapper

I was under the impression that I could use reference_wrapper to generate a functor that would return the object passed into the reference_wrapper ctor. But this isn't working. Am I doing it wrong? If so is there a better way to accomplish this? I can write a lambda, it just seems like I shouldn't have to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

void funPtrPrinter( function< int( void ) > output )
{
    cout << output() << endl;
}

int main( void )
{
    int thirteen = 13;
    auto refWrap = ref( thirteen );
    funPtrPrinter( refWrap );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is a way to accomplish this using `std::integral_constant`:

```
const int thirteen = 13;
auto refWrap = bind( &std::integral_constant< int, thirteen >::operator int, std::integral_constant< int, thirteen >() );
```

This does solve the question, but for all intents and purposes is inferior to the lambda:

```
const int thirteen = 13;
auto refWrap = [=](){ return thirteen; };
```

Answer (score 2):

A similar feature exists for member variables. Maybe you confused it with that.

```
struct foo { int bar; };
```

If you have a class with public member variables, you can use `std::mem_fn` and `std::bind` to create functors returning the value of the variable.

```
auto f = std::mem_fn(&foo::bar);
std::cout << f(foo{42}) << '\n';

auto g = std::bind(&foo::bar, foo{42});
std::cout << g() << '\n';
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need... but I can't use it on just any old stack variable.

Answer (score 1):

`std::reference_wrapper` doesn't generate functors. It is only a functor if original type is `Callable` - [`std::reference_wrapper::operator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator%28%29) is available only if stored reference is of callable type.

It's not clear why you need the functor at all, but if it's the case then lambda might be simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

`reference_wrapper` is only callable if the object it refers to is callable. Its `operator()` simply calls the referenced callable object. If the object refered to is not callable then `operator()` does not exist. In that sense it behaves just like a "real" reference.

`refWrap()` would be equivalent to `thirteen()`, so ill formed.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::reference_wrapper::operator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator%28%29) only participates in overload resolution if it's wrapping a callable object. An `int` isn't one, so what you're asking for won't work.

You could do this:

```
int thirteen = 13;
auto refWrap = bind( [&thirteen] { return thirteen; } );
funPtrPrinter( refWrap );
```

Now you have a callable, the `bind` expression, and that can be invoked within `funPtrPrinter()`.

If I were you, I'd skip the middleman and pass in a lambda.

```
int thirteen = 13;
funPtrPrinter( [&thirteen] { return thirteen; } );
```

Comment: @Oktalist Still editing :) The OP mentioned he didn't want to use a lambda (but not why), so I demonstrated an alternative.

Comment: This really is using a lambda inside a bind though.

Comment: @Jonathan Yes it is, and it's kinda silly to do that. Which is why you should pass the lambda directly.