# Pass Through Delayed Function Call

Tags: c++11, bind, functor

I have a lot of functors that I am passing to a function to do some testing work. My goal is to do these with `std::bind` and not use lambdas. But the very simple cases seem hard to do with `bind`. My first question was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256071/reference-wrapper-referencing-primitive).

Now I want to know if there is a pass through delayed function call that I can create with `bind`. Something like: `auto foo = std::bind( std::placeholders::_1 )` Such that `foo( 13 )` will return 13.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `bind` and not lambdas? What did lambdas ever do to you?

Comment: Mostly... I just used bind on the other methods so I wanted the symmetry. I will end up using lambdas if no one has a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same answer given on the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256071/reference-wrapper-referencing-primitive?lq=1):

So there is a way to accomplish this using `std::integral_constant`:

```
const int thirteen = 13;
auto refWrap = bind( &std::integral_constant< int, thirteen >::operator int, std::integral_constant< int, thirteen >() );
```

This does solve the question, but for all intents and purposes is inferior to the lambda:

```
const int thirteen = 13;
auto refWrap = [=](){ return thirteen; };
```